# La API KEY de google Maps no me deja ver el mapa

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una pagina web en la cual necesito que muestre diferentes ubicaciones pero tengo un problema al cargar el mapa, no me aparece nada solo me aparece una ventana con de Google traductor como si la pagina estuviera en ingles o algo así, ya hice todo lo referente a la API KEY, ya la tengo asociada a una cuenta de facturación, ya busque información en diferentes foros pero no eh encontrado la solución no se si me pudieran apoyar, de antemano muchas gracias les dejo la estructura del codigo.

```
 <src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../gmaps.js"></script>


var map;
function initMap(){
  map = new map({
   
    el: '#map',
    lat: 20.459360,
    lng: -100.624610
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    título: 'Lima',
    });
 
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    infoWindow: {
      content:'Lima'
    }
    });
```

la funcion initMap la tengo de esta forma

```
      function iniciarMap(){
      var coord = {lat:-34.5956145 ,lng: -58.4431949};
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
     zoom: 10,
    center: coord
   });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coord,
  map: map
  title: "lima"
  });
 }
```

y en  la pagina principal del div solo mando llamar

```
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>//FUNCION initMap
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"></script>
```